# Javascript - Dynamically add a value from input to the GET url

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have 3 simple **input filed's**

I need do **add dynamically** the **value** of the **input** to the **GET** request, I need to use only **vanilla js** for this.

My Html

```
<div class="action-container">
    <div class="action">
        <input class="input" id="player1" type="text">
        <div class="button" onclick="submit()">Submit</div>        
    </div>
    <div class="action">
        <input class="input" id="player2" type="text">
        <div class="button" onclick="submit()">Submit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
        <input class="input" id="player3" type="text">
        <div class="button" onclick="submit()">Submit</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS

```
function submit(){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var guessPlayer1 = document.getElementById('player1').value
    var guessPlayer2 = document.getElementById('player2').value
    var guessPlayer3 = document.getElementById('player3').value

    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
            console.log(http.response)
        }
    }

    http.open("GET", "https://Dummy-End-Point.com/" + guessPlayer1, true);
    http.send();

}
```

Comment: Looks like you have done it.  Whats the problem?

Comment: @Programnik, hello, i need that guessPlayer1 on the end point to be dynamic, and not hardcoded . If im thinking straight

Comment: It is dynamic.  Its a variable you are setting higher up in the code.

Comment: You mean if they click on player1, it should append player 1 value, player2, player 2 value etc?

Comment: @Programnik yes, thats is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `submit()` so it takes the ID as a parameter.

```js
function submit(id) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var guess = document.getElementById(id).value

  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      console.log(http.response)
    }
  }

  http.open("GET", "https://Dummy-End-Point.com/" + guess, true);
  http.send();

}
```

```html
<div class="action-container">
  <div class="action">
    <input class="input" id="player1" type="text">
    <div class="button" onclick="submit('player1')">Submit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <input class="input" id="player2" type="text">
    <div class="button" onclick="submit('player2')">Submit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <input class="input" id="player3" type="text">
    <div class="button" onclick="submit('player3')">Submit</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="action-container">
    <div class="action">
        <input class="input" id="player1" type="text">
        <div class="button" onclick="submit(this)">Submit</div>        
    </div>
    <div class="action">
        <input class="input" id="player2" type="text">
        <div class="button" onclick="submit(this)">Submit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
        <input class="input" id="player3" type="text">
        <div class="button" onclick="submit(this)">Submit</div>
    </div>
</div>

function submit(elem) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var guess = elem.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id; 

  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      console.log(http.response)
    }
  }

  http.open("GET", "https://Dummy-End-Point.com/" + guess, true);
  http.send();

}
```